# Mean and Variance of a functions of uniform random variable - as applied to a limiter

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, expectation

[image: a limiter operates as shown here]

**Question** - Evaluate the mean and variance of $Y$ if $X$=$U^3$ where $U$ is a **uniform random variable** in the unit interval [-1,1] and $a$$=$$1/2$ .

**Doubt** - if Y= g(X) , then i find myself perfectly able to solve the problem;

I would start with $E[Y]$= $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(X)\,f(x) dx$ and proceed.

However I'm a little bit unsure about the substitution of the required expression here, especially the limits that will vary.

If anyone could solve this, please help out. cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h(x)=x^3$ and $f$ be the PDF of $U$. Then we aim at finding the mean and variance of $Y=g(h(U))$. For the mean we have
$$
{\rm E}[Y]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(h(x))f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_{-1}^1g(x^3)f(x)\,\mathrm dx
$$
since $f(x)=0$ outside of $[-1,1]$. Now, note that $x\mapsto g(x^3)$ is an odd function (since it's a composition of two odd functions) and $f$ is an even function. Therefore $x\mapsto g(x^3)f(x)$ is an odd function and hence ${\rm E}[Y]=0$.

To compute the variance we note that $\mathrm{Var}(Y)={\rm E}[Y^2]$ since ${\rm E}[Y]=0$. For this we have
$$
{\rm E}[Y^2]=\int_{-1}^1 g(x^3)^2 f(x)\,\mathrm dx.
$$
Now we just need to find an expression for the function $x\mapsto g(x^3)^2$. First we have that 
$$
g(x^3)=
\begin{cases}
-a,\quad&\text{if }\; x\leq -b,\\
x^3,&\text{if }\; -b< x<b,\\
a,&\text{if }\; x\geq b,
\end{cases}
$$
with $b=a^{1/3}$ and hence
$$
g(x^3)^2=
\begin{cases}
x^6,\quad &\text{if }\; -b<x<b,\\
a^2,&\text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

This enables us to split up the integral accordingly:
$$
\int_{-1}^1 g(x^3)^2f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_{-1}^{-b} g(x^3)^2 f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_{-b}^b g(x^3)^2f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_b^1 g(x^3)^2f(x)\,\mathrm dx.
$$

Comment: One might recommend to use the PDF of U, otherwise one needs to compute the PDF of X, a cumbersome and not useful task.

Comment: @Did: You're right. I misread $X$ as $U$. Thank you.

Comment: Right. Another thing: rereading the question, it is obvious that Y is symmetric hence E(Y)=0 and the real job is to compute E(Y^2).

Comment: @Did: I overlooked that. Hopefully the answer is more helpful now. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. +1. And I like that you leave something to do to the OP, so that they can check they understand the solution.

Comment: Thank you ! Could someone explain how the conclusion-  $g(x^3)$ is a composition of two functions - is deduced ? I know what a composite function is but I can't see why $g(x^3)$ is one in this problem. Would I be right if I'm considering it is so because of $g(x)$ and $u^3$ ?

Comment: @Raaj: This is straightforward. To go from $x$ to $g(x^3)$ we first go from $x$ to $x^3$ and then apply $g$ on that. As stated in the answer $g(x^3)=(g\circ h)(x)$, where $h(x)=x^3$. So it's the composition of $g$ and $h$.